# Call php in HTML form on action but don't redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an HTML form as follows:

```
<form id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm" method="post" action="emailinfo.php">
```

and then a submit button that calls `verify()`:

```
<a href="#" class="button1" onClick="verify()">Send</a>
```

`verify` is defined as such:

```
function verify() {
    if(document.getElementById("name").value=="" || document.getElementById("email").value=="") {
        alert("Please enter a name and an email.");
    } else {
        alert("Looks good, sending email");
        document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Currently, when I click the submit button, the browser redirects to `emailinfo.php`, which is just a blank white screen because that `php` file just sends off an email and does nothing else. How can I run that `php` file without redirecting to it?

Comment: ajax is best suits to your condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function verify() {
 if(document.getElementById("name").value=="" || document.getElementById("email").value=="") {
    alert("Please enter a name and an email.");
 } else {
    alert("Looks good, sending email");
    //document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit();
    var name=$('#name').val();
    var email=$('#email').val();
    var  formData = "name="+name+"&email="+email;
    $.ajax({
        url : "emailinfo.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            //data - response from server
            alert(data);
        },

    });
  }
}

</script>
<form id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm" method="post" action="">
<input  type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input  type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<a href="#" class="button1" onClick="verify()">Send</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is use AJAX to send a request to the emailinfo.php file when the button is clicked. Making the form action blank will cause the form to post to the same page you're on.

If you're using jQuery, it's pretty easy to submit the form via ajax:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.button1').click(function(){
        var f = $('#ContactForm');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "emailinfo.php",
          data: f.serialize()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using only javascript. how would I do this in javascript

Answer (score 2):

ContactFormFirst change that `a` tag to a button, then assign that `verify()` to its onclick. then in  `verify()`. use ajax to post the values from your form to `emailinfo.php`.

u can use

```
    $.post( 
        "emailinfo.php", 
        $( "#ContactForm" ).serialize(),
        function( data ) { 
           /* do things with responce */
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in this scenario is ajax, but if you do not want to use ajax, you can simply add 'return false' for it not to be redirected when using form submit:

```
function verify() 
{
  if(document.getElementById("name").value=="" ||document.getElementById("email").value=="") 
  {
    alert("Please enter a name and an email.");

  } 
  else 
  {
    alert("Looks good, sending email");
    document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit();
    return false;
  }
}
```